# Can't find node by id in dom-if template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

After download Polymer Starter Kit, I included a dom-if template inside (nested) the dom-bind template in index.html to hide the entire UI when user is not authenticated. However, I can’t get dom-if elements using app.$$(‘#id’) feature.

I’m trying to access the paperDrawerPanel in the app.closeDrawer funcion (app.js)

```
app.closeDrawer = function () {
    console.log(app.$$('#paperDrawerPanel')); //returns null
};
```

How can I access that element?

**Edit 1**

This is the html part:

```
...
<body unresolved>
    <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

        <auth-login id="auth" user="{{user}}" is-authenticated="{{isAuthenticated}}"" location="https://i2bserver.firebaseio.com"></auth-login>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isAuthenticated}}">
            <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" drawer-width="220px" responsive-width="1100px">
...
```

**Edit 2**

I guess in the moment that app.closeDrawer is called by the routing.html the dom-if elements should already be tamped.

Here is the code that call app.closeDrawer (routing.html from PSK):

```
function closeDrawer(ctx, next) {
  app.closeDrawer();
  next();
}

// Routes
page('*', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
  next();
});
```

Comment: Are they shown? You cant query elements that don't exist and if the `dom-if` expression is false, these elements don't exist. If you need this use hidden instead of dom-if.

Comment: yes, they are shown (if condition is true when trying to access the element)

Comment: Please add more code and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.$$` queries inside the DOM scope of `element`. In your case, `app` is a template whose job is to stamp DOM into the enclosing scope (`body`).

Try `document.querySelector('#paperDrawerPanel')`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element’s local DOM, use the $$ method:
>
> `this.$$(selector)`
>
> `$$` returns the first node in the local DOM that matches `selector`.

That means you have to add a `#` symbol to reference the element using its `id`. Your code

```
app.closeDrawer = function () {
  console.log(app.$$('paperDrawerPanel')); //returns null
};
```

should work if written like this

```
app.closeDrawer = function () {
  console.log(app.$$('#paperDrawerPanel'));
};
```

Comment: very sorry, but I already used # in selector, just forgot to put in this example. still not working. I'll edit